# Double compare in JavaScript looks weird

Tags: javascript, boolean, compare, boolean-expression

Let's `var a = "first", b = "second", c = "first";`.
Expression `a == c` returns `true`, (of course!); `a == c` is `true` too.
Then why does `a == a == c` return `false`?

**Example**

```js
var a = "first", b = "second", c = "first";

write( a != b != c );
write( a == b != c );
write( a == b == c );
write( a != b == c );
write("");
write( a == a == c );

// -------------------
function write(val) {document.querySelector("console").innerHTML += "<hr noshade size='1px' color='#eee'>" + String(val);}
```

```html
<console></console>
```

Comment: Because `a == a == c` is comparing `true` to `"first"`.

Comment: Also don't use loose comparison. Just to confuse you: `1 == 1 == 1` is actually `true` (`1 === 1 === 1` is not).

Comment: `1 == 1 == 1` comparing `truthy` values `(true and 1)` at end so `true` and `1 === 1 === 1` and comparing types as well `boolean`  `true` with `number` `1` yields false. @FelixKling right isnt it

Comment: @vinayakj: Not just truthy values. `"foo" == 1` also compares truthy values, but is `false`. But `Number(true) === 1`, hence `true == 1` "works".

Comment: Yes, `"first" == true` returns `false`; while `!!"first" == true` returns `true`.

Comment: But it is because of type conversion.

Comment: @FelixKling but `"foo"` is also truthy value

Comment: @vinayakj: That's what I'm saying: It does not work for *every* truthy value (like you seem to imply in your first comment), only for values that coerce to `1`.

Comment: @vinayakj ... if `typeof value == "boolean"`

Comment: @FelixKling interesting, so only `true==1` & `1==1` is true but anything else is false

Comment: @vinayakj: `"1" == 1`, `[1] == 1` and `["1"] == 1` are `true` as well.

Comment: @FelixKling  ohh.. okk.. `"1" == 1` understood, how could `[1] == 1` and `["1"] == 1` are. where could I find more info on this. Thanks for all clarifications.

Comment: @vinayakj: Have a look at the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the link to the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because what is really happening is this:

```
(a == a) == c
```

Which is really just:

```
true == "first"
```

See [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Oh, left-to-right, sure. Dumb me :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because it goes from left to right, one `==` at a time and the result of each previous `==` operation is a boolean:

```
(a == a) === true
(true == c) === false
```

---

You need to do:

```
a == a && a == c
```

or better yet (since this is JavaScript):

```
a === a && a === c
```

Alternatively, can write in **CoffeeScript**, which will translate:

```
a == a == c
```

into

```
(a === a && a === c);
```

for you.

Answer (score 0):

`a == c` returns a boolean (`true`).

Since `a` is not a boolean, it cannot possibly equal `a == c`.